# How to put JSON data in html / javascript grid table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following JSON-formatted data:

```
    [
{
    "ID": "00:50:c2:63:10:1a",
    "start": "1349773838277760",
    "end": "1349773838277770",
    "startArea": "areaStart",
    "endArea": "areaEnd",
    "duration": "10"
},
{
    "ID": "00:50:c2:63:10:1a",
    "start": "1349773838277760",
    "end": "1349773838277780",
    "startArea": "areaStart",
    "endArea": "areaEnd",
    "duration": "20"
},
{
    "ID": "00:50:c2:63:10:1a",
    "start": "1349773838277760",
    "end": "1349773838277780",
    "startArea": "areaStart",
    "endArea": "areaEnd",
    "duration": "20"
}]
```

How can I display this data nicely in a html data table?

Is there a plugin for jQuery that can help me?

My basic approach is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LKkSJ/

Comment: I have added this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKkSJ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

http://codecanyon.net/item/graphup-jquery-plugin/108025?ref=1stwebdesigner

These are solutions that are very good for these kinds of tables

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend dataTables, you can feed in a javascript array. [Click here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Answer (score 4):

[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) can create a table from JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

If DataTables is too heavy for you (70 KB) you can use the various template libraries out there:

- [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com),
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com),
- [Distal](http://code.google.com/p/distal)

Just convert a table row into a template and then repeat that template inside an HTML table.