# Passing dynamic json data to populate jquery grid

Tags: jquery, json

I have to create a grid with undefined columns which is based on Json data,

```
[{
    Name: "John",
    Designation: "Analyst",
    Age: 25, 
    Department: "IT"
},
{
    Name: "Matthew",
    Designation: "Manager", 
    Age: 38, 
    Department: "Accounts"
},
{
    Name: "Emma",
    Designation: "Senior Manager",
    Age: 40,
    Department: "HR"
}];
```

My desired output is as below:

As header:

```
Name | Designation | Age | Department
```

As datarow:

```
John | Analyst | 25 | IT
```

Please, anyone help me how I have to start and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Question [How to put JSON data in html / javascript grid table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012390/how-to-put-json-data-in-html-javascript-grid-table)  [if you check before posting]
this is datatables --http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html
this is gridtable JS --http://backgridjs.com/#examples

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(Jsonstring,function(){
  alert(JsonString.Name);
  alert(JsonString.Designation)
  alert(JsonString.Age)
  alert(JsonString.Department)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here i have iterated and displayed the data in table format is this is what you are looking for [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RUemz/6/)

```
$table = "<table id = 'resultTable' border=1>";
$.each(data[0] , function(key, value){
   $table += "<td>"+key+"</td>";
});
$table += "<tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    $table += "<tr>";

    var it = data[i];



    $table += "<td>" + data[i].Name + "</td>";

    $table += "<td>" + data[i].Designation + "</td>";

    $table += "<td>" + data[i].Age + "</td>";

    $table += "<td>" + data[i].Department + "</td>";

    //alert(items[i].duration);
    $table += "</tr>";

}

$table += "</table>";

$('body').append($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **for...in loop** will exactly do what you need.

Here is what the Mozilla Developer Network writes about it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

While inside the "for...in loop it's crucial that you test if the property has the specified property and that this property isn't inherited. ([hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty))

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ecoqax/1/edit

I'm using jQuery here:

```
var $theader = $("thead"),
    $tbody = $("tbody"),
    hasHeader = false,
    html = "";

  // data is the converted JSON data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // the current person
    var person = data[i];

    html += '<tr>';

    // iterating over every property of the person object
    for (var prop in person) {
      if (person.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // insert the header once
        if (hasHeader === false) {
          $theader.append($('<th>'+prop+'</th>'));
        }
        html += '<td>'+person[prop]+'</td>';
      }
    }

    // after the first iteration the header is added
    hasHeader = true;
    html += '</tr>';
  }

  $tbody.append($(html));
```