# How to work on two different arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending two different JSON array as response from servlet to jquery(ajax call).

Say jsonarray1

```
["E1134","2015-08-22 00:00:00","SK5012","2015-08-21 00:00:00","1621122","2015-08-01 00:00:00","2"]
```

Need to pass these to some text fields like E1134 -- Empid text field etc.,

jsonarray2

```
[{"slno":"1","itemname":"MCB DOUBLE POLE 10A -LEGRAND","itemcode":"2102MCBAC2P10A04","supplier":"SREE KUMAR AGENCIES","receivedqty":"200","rejectedqty":"0","acceptedqty":"200"},{"slno":"2","itemname":"MCB DOUBLE POLE 10A DC -LEGRAND","itemcode":"2102MCBDC2P10A04","supplier":"SREE KUMAR AGENCIES","receivedqty":"106","rejectedqty":"0","acceptedqty":"106"}]
```

These response will be passed to table like

```js
$.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
          var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                    rowNew.children().eq(0).html('<img src="idata.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="popup-trigger">');
                     rowNew.children().eq(1).append(i);
                    rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemname']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['itemcode']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['receivedqty']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['rejectedqty']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(6).text(value['acceptedqty']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text" class="tb1"/>');
                        rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                        i++;
                });
```

`jsonarray1` needs to be populated in some text fields. `jsonarray2` needs to be populated in table

I am struck with how to get those separately so that I can pass to the required fields. For example response1 for text fields and response2 for tables. Please someone help me on this

```js
try{
   Connection con=QCConProvider.getConnection();
   PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("query1");
   ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
   
   if (!rs.next() ) {
    System.out.println("no data");
   }else {
    existqcmaster = true;
    irepno = rs.getString("valu");
    cdate = rs.getString("cdate");
    vinvno = rs.getString("vinvno");
    vinvdt = rs.getString("vinvdt");
    pono = rs.getString("pono");
    podt = rs.getString("podt");
    unit = rs.getString("unit");
   }
   
            //close all connection here.
   
  }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }
       
     JSONArray masterdata = new JSONArray();//o/p1 - should send back to ajax
     masterdata.put(irepno);
     //pass all values to masterdata
     System.out.println(masterdata);
     System.out.println(masterdata.length());     
     
     if (existqcmaster) {
      System.out.println("qc details available");
      ArrayList<Elements> inspdata = new ArrayList<Elements>();
      inspdata=Fetchinsp.getElements(irepno);      
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(inspdata, new TypeToken<List<Elements>>() {}.getType());
      JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
      response.getWriter().print(jsonArray); // o/p2 - should send back to ajax
     }
     response.setContentType("application/json");
   //  response.getWriter().print(masterdata); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, note that what you have are arrays. They are nothing to do with JSON at all. Secondly, please give details about the code you've written so far and also the HTML structure you're trying to create. It seems that all you need is a loop (or two)

Comment: Can you post the code which is handling your ajax calls. And explain what you want to do with the return values, that's not really clear from your question imo.

Comment: so you're not able to do two separate calls for each array?

Comment: @LuudJacobs: edited my code. Please check it

Comment: @AlanSutherland: no: in one call i am trying to get all required values.Please see my code

Comment: why can't you do two separate calls?

Answer (score 0):

To create array from json:

var arrayOfJSon = $.parseJSON(jsonarray1);

To Populate textField by some string value:

$(".SomeTextFieldsClass").val = arrayOfJSon[0];

To create table populated by jSon: 
[How to put JSON data in html / javascript grid table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012390/how-to-put-json-data-in-html-javascript-grid-table)